# Finding the shortest path, and retracing/returning it as an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I'm working through The Odin Project curriculum, and have come across the Knight Travails assignment, which I'm pretty sure is the 'Minimum Knight Moves' from LeetCode with extra steps.

The assignment is as follows :

1. Put together a script that creates a game board and a knight.
2. Treat all possible moves the knight could make as children in a tree. Don’t allow any moves to go off the    board.
3. Decide which search algorithm is best to use for this case. Hint: one of them could be a potentially infinite series.
4. Use the chosen search algorithm to find the shortest path between the starting square (or node) and the ending square. Output what that full path looks like, e.g.:

```js
  > knightMoves([3,3],[4,3])
  => You made it in 3 moves!  Here's your path:
    [3,3]
    [4,5]
    [2,4]
    [4,3]
```

This is the current iteration of my solution. It's not identical to what the assignment requests, but I think it's close enough :

```js
'use strict'
class Traversal {
  constructor (x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.xDir = [-1, 1, -1, 1, -2, -2, 2, 2] // LEFT-RIGHT
    this.yDir = [2, 2, -2, -2, 1, -1, 1, -1] // UP-DOWN
  }

  calculateMoves (targetX = 0, targetY = 0) {
    const viableMoves = [] // coords of the locations the knight can reach from his current position
    let queue = [[this.x, this.y]]
    const visited = new Set()
    let steps = 0 // holds the minimal amount of moves to reach the target
    for (let i = 0; i < this.xDir.length && i < this.yDir.length; i++) {
      viableMoves.push([(this.x + this.xDir[i]), (this.y + this.yDir[i])]) // this will correctly calculate  viable moves I think? sure seems to work in the console
    }
    queue = [...viableMoves] // populate the queue with moves the knight can make at this moment

    while (queue.length) {
      const next = []
      while (queue.length) {
        const current = queue.shift()
        const currentX = current[0] // extract current position from the queue
        const currentY = current[1] // extract current position from the queue
        if (currentX === targetX && currentY === targetY) { // we've found our goal if this is truthy
          return steps
        }
        for (const d of viableMoves) { 
          const nextX = currentX + d[0]
          const nextY = currentY + d[1]

          if (!visited.has(`${nextX},${nextY}`)) { // this entire part might have to be rewritten, I barely understand wtf this is
            visited.add(`${nextX},${nextY}`)
            next.push([nextX, nextY])
          }
        }
      }
      steps++
      queue = next
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected - instantiate a Traversal object, and call the calculateMoves method with whatever location you're trying to reach. It will return the minimal amount of moves necessary to reach it.

However, I still have to implement a way to detect an actual path to the target, and return it as an array.

I'm a bit out of my comfort zone with this. The only thing I can think of is that I could use another array to hold the coordinates that bring you closer to the target, but it should hold... what exactly?

It's also worth noting that this implementation assumes the chess board is infinite in all directions, and coordinates can take on negative values. Not sure if that massively impacts the viable solutions here.

I will rewrite this from scratch if necessary.

Comment: *"Not sure if that massively impacts the viable solutions here."* It sure does. The number of moves from (0, 0) to (1, 1) when no negative values are allowed, is 4. Your code returns 1 which doesn't make sense even with negative values.

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are some issues in your code:

- The viable moves are not calculated correctly in the inner loop: they are initialised as moves from the initial position, but then the inner loop adds a new position to that -- which is only correct if the initial position was (0, 0), but otherwise will give wrong coordinates.
- The number of steps returned is not correct. For instance, if on the first move the target is found, the function will return 0, while it should return 1.
- You probably should not allow negative values for the coordinates as this surely has an impact on the result. For instance, with negative values allowed, the number of steps from (0, 0) to (1, 1) is 2, but when they are not allowed, then 4 steps are needed.
- In the first part of your code you put positions on the queue without marking them as visited.

Then to your question: to get the path, change your Set to a Map, and for each key in that map store the *preceding* position as value. With that information you can walk back from the target to the source and reconstruct a path from that.

Here is how that could be achieved:

```js
class Traversal {
  static dir = [[-1, 2], [1, 2], [-1, -2], [1, -2], [-2, 1], [-2, -1], [2, 1], [2, -1]];

  constructor (x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
  }

  calculateMoves (targetX = 0, targetY = 0) {
    const target = `${targetX},${targetY}`;
    let queue = [[this.x, this.y]];
    const visited = new Map().set(`${this.x},${this.y}`, null);
    let steps = 0;
    
    while (queue.length) {
      if (visited.has(target)) {
        // Reconstruct path
        let point = [targetX, targetY];
        const path = [];
        while (point) {
            path.push(point);
            point = visited.get(point.join(","));
        }
        return path.reverse();
      };
      const next = [];
      for (const [currentX, currentY] of queue) {
        const viableMoves = Traversal.dir.map(([dx, dy]) => 
            [currentX + dx, currentY + dy]
        ).filter(([x, y]) => 
            x >= 0 && y >= 0 && !visited.has(`${x},${y}`) && visited.set(`${x},${y}`, [currentX, currentY])
        );
        next.push(...viableMoves);
      }
      steps++;
      queue = next;
    }
  }
}

// Demo run
const path = new Traversal(0, 0).calculateMoves(1, 1);
console.log(path);
```